# SQL query to extract based on two conditions

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have four tables in this structure

```
cars - id | brand | type | license
equipments - id | name | description
distances - id_car | date | distance
cars_equipments - id_car | id_equipment
```

and i have to extract all cars that have equipment "fire extinguisher" that were driving yesterday...

I have managed to create this so far

```
SELECT cars.id, cars.brand, cars.type, cars.license, cars_equipments.id_car 
FROM equipments 
INNER JOIN cars_equipments ON equipments.id = cars_equipments.id_equipment 
INNER JOIN cars ON cars.id = cars_equipments.id_car 
INNER JOIN distances ON distances.id_car = cars.id
WHERE equipments.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher'
```

this returns only one car having 'fire extinguisher' so it's not working properly, and if I add

```
AND distances.date = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

to combine that with the last day it doesn't work.

Comment: Which DBMS is this? Why is the query not working properly if it returns results?

Comment: in mySQL it just returns blank when i add the date_sub()

Comment: because it returns only one car (there are 2), plus when I add the date_sub it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you?

```
SELECT cars.id, cars.brand, cars.type, cars.license, cars_equipments.id_car 
FROM cars 
   INNER JOIN cars_equipments ON cars.id = cars_equipments.id_car 
   INNER JOIN equipments ON equipments.id = cars_equipments.id_equipment 
   INNER JOIN distances ON distances.id_car = cars.id
WHERE equipments.name LIKE 'fire extinguisher'
AND distances.date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),-1)
AND distances.date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Check this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e93/1)